# convert private matrix form int to double c++

Tags: c++

i wanna convert the private member matrix[] from int to double , i tried to convert it by using the function transform() ? when i input the values
ex. matrix[i]= 90.9
it doesn't ceiling the value and doesn't convert it , where is the wrong?

Thanks.

```
  class A
    {
    private : int matrix[10];
    public:
     A();
    void inputMatrix();
     void transformMatrix();
    };
    void A::inputMatrix()
    {
    for(int i=0; i<10 ; i++)
    cin>>matrix[i];
    }
   void A::transform()
   {
        ceil(matrix[i]);
        double matrix = static_cast<double>(matrix[i]);
        cout << matrix[i] ;
   }
```

Comment: `double matrix = static_cast<double>(matrix[i]);` -- Why are you naming another variable `matrix`?  Doesn't that line look a little confusing to you?  Also, don't you need a `double matrix_of_double[10]` to copy values into?

Comment: This code cannot compile. In `ceil(matrix[i]);` there is no `i`. In addition `ceil` on an `int` is pointless. `int` has no fraction to round up. `double matrix = static_cast<double>(matrix[i]);`changes `matrix` to a single `double` value. This means `int matrix[10];` is no longer accessible as `matrix`. You can't do what you seem to be trying to do here.

Comment: `ceil9matrix[I]` doesn't change anything and the returned value isn't assigned. I'm assuming ints and doubles are both 64 bits. It's not doing what you think. It looks like you should use a union with arrays of doubles and ints. Then you can convert from one to the other in the same locations.

Comment: In `transform` you are ceiling an `int` value. `int` has no digits after a decimal point. `a == ceil(a)` is true for all `int a`. What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: You should read how to create a [mcve]. Your code snippet doesn't compile. Once the method is called `transform` and once `transformMatrix`

Comment: You declared a constructor but you didn't define it.

Comment: i need the idea only , i forgot the loop and function name in this code the question is how can i input int array and convert it to double , i think i should define double array and copy matrix array !!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You can't read floating point numbers into `int` values. That means that `matrix` stores integers. It is pointless to use `ceil` on integers, since `a == ceil(a)` for all `int a`. I think, this is a [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to input floating point numbers and save them in `matrix`, you have to define `matrix` as `float` or `double` array:

```
private:
  double matrix[10];
```

Then you can use `ceil` to round up your values. But you have to save or print the result. Either use

```
double ceilValue = ceil(matrix[i]);
```

or

```
std::cout << ceil(matrix[i]);
```

Since you are using a variable `i`, I assume that you want to print or round each value of `matrix`. Therefor you need a loop like `for` or `while`:

```
for (int i(0); i < 10; i++) {
  std::cout << ceil(matrix[i]);
}
```

After you fixed these points and the errors mentioned in the comments, your code should work as expected.

Comment: i forgot the loop , but i have to define int matrix and convert it to double

Comment: You can't read floating point numbers into `int` values.

Comment: yes sir , i think it is a wrong question !!